# How to call non-static method from another class in an Android Application

Tags: java, android

So I am trying to call a method once an item is tapped in an Android application.

This is where the method I want to call is `getFavourites();`

```
public class Favourites extends Activity {
    public void getFavourites(){
        ViewFlipper viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
        viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
        setTitle("Favourites");
    }
}
```

Here is where I want to call the method `getFavourtites();`

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_favourite) {
        Favourites getFav = new Favourites();
        getFav.getFavourites();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_search) {
        ViewFlipper viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
        viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
        setTitle("Search");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_sendFeedback) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

I don't really know what I am doing wrong but every time I run it, the app just crash.

EDIT: here is the full stack for favourites

```
package com.ctt.mrdan.croydontramtime2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

/**
 * Created by MrDan on 16/07/2016.
 */
public class Favourites extends Activity {
    public void getFavourites(){
        ViewFlipper viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
        viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
        setTitle("Favourites");
    }
}
```

Here is the full stack for the Main

```
package com.ctt.mrdan.croydontramtime2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_favourite) {
            Favourites getFav = new Favourites();
            getFav.getFavourites();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_search) {
            ViewFlipper viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
            viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
            setTitle("Search");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sendFeedback) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post your stack trace.   I bet you're getting a null pointer exception on either your ViewFlipper or your DrawerLayout but it's impossible to tell for sure without the stack trace.

Comment: You can't create an Activity in that way. Post the full code of both classes please

Comment: @MichaelJCaboose I have posted the full code

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler I have posted the full code

Comment: Logcat error msgs please..!

Comment: @DanielOMensah A stack trace is a report of the error that occurred.  In Android Studio it appears in the LogCat panel which is likely at the bottom of your Android Studio window.  There should be several tabs.  Click on the one that says LogCat.  If the exception is the last thing that happened, there should be a bunch of red text detailing it. However, I believe that Juan is correct. The way that you're instantiating the Activity is wrong. See https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: You could implement the `getFavourites` method in the `MainActivity`. There is no point in the `Favourites` activity class with that one method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're instantiating `Favourites` and then calling `getFavourites()` on the new instance. `getFavourites()` calls `findViewById()`, which implicitly calls `getWindow().findViewById()`, but the `Activity` has no content view, resulting in a `NullPointerException`.

`Favourites` has no purpose at all.

You could just move the code from `getFavourites()` to `onNavigationItemSelected()`:

```
viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);

// ...

if (id == R.id.nav_favourite) {
    viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
    setTitle("Favourites");
} else if (id == R.id.nav_search) {
    viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
    setTitle("Search");
}
```

Also, you should **never** instantiate an `Activity` with the `new` keyword. Use `Intent` and leave the instantiation to the `ActivityManager`.